# Qlikview - report CPU and RAM consumption for each .qvw file separately

Tags: memory, cpu-usage, qlikview

We have QV server and want to know how much CPU and RAM is each app consuming. Is it posible? Are there some log files that have these information? Or Win perfmon?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what with QlikView Optimizer application? It uses .mem files and there are some size values of each object in document, but I cant find out, if the sum of these values is the size of document in memory and if these files could be generated automatically. Does somebody have experience with .mem files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Not I am not 100% that the Qlikview Management Console already comes with something like this but I know that there is an app that I came across on the Qlikview community that a member created. That might just be what you are looking for. Try looking into the QV Governance Dashboard.

Comment: Thanks! However, Governance Dashboard shows only VM and RAM committed by QVS

Answer (score 0):

See the QlikView Server log files (Performance, Sessions, Audit). That's a txt file delimited by tab and register all in real time.
Probably locate on "C:\ProgramData\QlikTech\QlikViewServer\Performance_SERVERNAME.log".

Comment: yes, i'm reporting these log files now, but there is only virtual memory comitted by whole qlikview server...